# cdk import `As part of the import operation, you cannot modify or add [RoleArn]`

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a stack A that contains VPC. By duplicating code to the stack B I tried to import CDK import B . In the dialogue I put all needed ID of resources, at the end I got the error  `As part of the import operation, you cannot modify or add [RoleArn]`
My goal is moving some resource between stacks because I'm reaching the limit of 500 resources per stack.

Update: I use `cdk import` subcommand in the terminal

```
cdk import [STACK]

Import existing resource(s) into the given STACK
```

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "tried to import", are you referring to using the Vpc.from* methods? If so, importing resources into a stack this way is only used for making references, or reading, those resources, and any modifications to them is usually not allowed.

Comment: @MatthewBonig - I have updated the question. I talk about `cdk import`  subcommand

Answer (score 2):

This is because the CloudFormation stack needs to be created first, before you can import into it.

Under the hood, CDK is trying to use CreateChangeSet:IMPORT, but there is no stack yet to change, which is where you get this odd attribute `RoleArn` from,  it's not part of the resources you could coalesce.

To fix, before importing, comment out all resources (ie constructs in CDK) in your stack. Then run `cdk deploy` to create the initial empty stack that you can import into then.